# Mysql query specific output

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum, pivot

I'm trying to get an output such as:

```
Year | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December

Year | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December
```

..and so on.

Each `month` column should have its own `SUM(price)` for that `Month` and the `Year` in question. Wherever comes blank (for example, maybe `2020 March` is empty) should be blank/zero.

Query so far:

```
SELECT Year(date) AS y, monthname(date) AS m, SUM(price) AS p 
FROM orders GROUP BY monthname(date), Year(date) ORDER BY date
```

Its returning as this:

```
2020 January someSum
2020 February anotherSum
```

...etc

Any way to make it return the results as above left to right rather than up-down or am I just that tired and need to go to sleep? I feel I'm confusing something horribly. Someone clarify it for me or chastise me mightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    year(date) year_date,
    sum(case when month(date) = 1 then  price end) January,
    sum(case when month(date) = 2 then  price end) February,
    sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) March,
    ...
from orders
group by year(date)
order by year_date
```

Comment: Sheesh. I knew my brain remembered something about this but couldn't pin it down. Thank you! Worked like a charm.